# Store in local database when remote SQL Server unavailable and then sync when connected

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am developing a C# Windows Forms app for event management. There will be 15 gates with RFID readers. These readers will read the UID and query the database to check if it is unique entry for that day.

Now if for some reason, SQL Server is not available, I want the app to store the data in a local database and sync as soon as the connectivity is restored.

Any idea on how should I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of data? Is it not critical that the RFID scan can lookup a valid entry in the live DB? Or is it not that kind of 'gate'? Are you currently calling off to the live DB? Any ORM in place? If so, use the same mechanism to connect locally instead. Rather than treat this is as a 'wait for a connection then insert records' task, approach it as a 'I will insert records at regular intervals, and postpone it if there is currently no connection' requirement. Just my recommendation. Until you're more specific, it's hard to help with the technical details.

Comment: Mobile applications have this requirement for years (10+) - back when *mobile* meant a PDA. This is provided out of the box for many years now using the Microsoft Sync framework and/or various variants of SQL Server Compact etc. Lately, it's available as a service to mobile applications. I don't know the current status (or names) of these offerings but there are a *lot* of them.

Comment: Also note that synchronizing databases isn't trivial - there *will* be conflicts. It's far easier to use a queue to hold and forward messages/commands to the server than try to sync and handle conflicts

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL Server replication, and install SQL Server Express with a local copy of the database on each device.